# How can I get Integer from a string containing numbers,characters?

Tags: java, string

I was trying to get an `int`  (serial number of a student) from a `string` looks like "122. Fardinabir 170213" , where "122" is his serial number.

Before this, I tried using `nextInt()` method with a `Scanner` of the `String`, but nextInt() failed to do the job.

Then I have tried this procces...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class tempfile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int serial_int = 0;
        String serial_st;
        serial_st =  find_serial("122. FardinAbir 170213") ;
        System.out.println(serial_st);
        serial_int = Integer.parseInt(serial_st);
        System.out.println(serial_int);
    }
    public static String find_serial(String st)
    {
        String[] parts = st.split(" ");   //  the first serial part will remain in parts[0]
        parts[0].replaceAll("[\\D]", ""); //  As I know it will remove non integer and the pure int serial will remain
        return parts[0];  
    }
}
```

But, `replaceAll("[\\D]", "")` is not working...

Can anyone please help me to solve this or find a way out to this job...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is the serial number always 3 digits? and is that always the format?

Comment: `String` is immutable, try `parts[0] = parts[0].replaceAll("[\\D]", "")` .

Comment: no serial number can be made of any digits.

Comment: yaah... it works... thanks...@Berger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String line = "122. FardinAbir 170213";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if(matcher.find()) {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

Comment: I would use `"^(\\d+)"` since OP just needs leading digits.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you also want to get the rest of the string eventually you can use Regex groups

```
String line = "122. FardinAbir 170213";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.\\s+([^\\s]+)\\s+(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("serial: " + matcher.group(1));
    int serial = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("group 2: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("group 3: " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

nextInt() probably did not work because scanner expects newline separation

Answer (score 1):

Since you tried using `nextInt` it seems you just want leading digits, which means you can use the following regex code:

```
public static String find_serial(String st) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^\\d+").matcher(st);
    return (m.find() ? m.group() : null);
}
```

You could also rely in the serial ending with a period, though that doesn't validate that serial is all digits:

```
public static String find_serial(String st) {
    int idx = st.indexOf('.');
    return (idx > 0 ? st.substring(0, idx) : null);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This'll do:

```
public static int getSerialNumber() {
    String id = "122. Fardinabir 170213";
    int place = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < id.length();i++) {
        if(id.charAt(i) == '.') {
            place = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(id.substring(0, place));
}
```

**EDIT:** you can also do it like this:

```
public static int getSerialNumber(String name) {
    return Integer.parseInt(name.substring(0, name.indexOf('.')));
}
```

thanks @Andreas for that solution.

Comment: I was seeking for something else , without using a loop and that process...thank you

Comment: Why use loop when `indexOf('.')` will do it for you?

Comment: @Andreas true, but maybe there are multiple dots in the input (probably not, but this is safer)

Comment: @PieterMantel In what way does your code differ from `indexOf` when there are multiple dots? They both find the first dot.

Comment: @Andreas I thought indexOf found the last dot... then it is also a good (maybe better) option to use `indexOf(".")`. I guess you learn something new every day :P

Comment: @PieterMantel `lastIndexOf('.')` finds the last one.

Comment: @Andreas 6 minutes ago you said: _"In what way does your code differ from indexOf when there are multiple dots? They both find the first dot"_ suggesting that it finds the first

Comment: @PieterMantel Sorry, didn't know you were dyslexic, so hopefully if I show them to you side-by-side, you'll see the difference: [`indexOf('.')`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) finds *first* dot, and [`lastIndexOf('.')`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-) finds *last* dot.

Comment: @PieterMantel Didn't know being helpful is considered rude. Would it have been less rude to say *"I said `lastIndexOf`, not `indexOf`"*? Or how should I have said it to not hurt your feelings? Please *help* me learn not to be rude.